# Bash regex: Grep for tilde '~' and hyphen '-' on array loop

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm trying to create an `expect_commands` bash function to check for a regex to be on a file:

```
function expect_commands 
{
        args_array=()
        for (( i = 2; i <= $#; i++ )); do
            args_array[i]=${!i}
            if grep -Fxqe "${args_array[$i]}" "$hist_file" || grep -Fxqe "${args_array[$i]}/" "$hist_file" || grep -Fxqe "${args_array[$i]} " "$hist_file" || grep -FxqE "${args_array[$i]}" "$hist_file"
            then
                response "$1" $COUNT
            else
                tell_error "$1" $COUNT
            fi
        done
}
```

The function is called with the following arguments:

```
expect_commands "remove entire ~/workspace/test-website/css directory" "rm -r test-website/css" "rm -r test-website/css/" "rm -Rf ~/workspace/test-website/css" "rm -rf ~/workspace/test-website/css" "rm -R ~/workspace/test-website/css"
```

Where argument `$1` is the task.
Arguments from `$2` to the end are each of the possible combinations that the user may input to the terminal.

These inputs are saved into the `~/.bash_history` file and evaluated from there with `grep`:

```
if grep -Fxqe "${args_array[$i]}" "$hist_file" || grep -Fxqe "${args_array[$i]}/" "$hist_file" || grep -Fxqe "${args_array[$i]} " "$hist_file" || grep -FxqE "${args_array[$i]}" "$hist_file"
```

The function passes with inputs like:

`rm -r test-website/css`
`rm -r test-website/css/`

But when it comes to:

`rm -Rf ~/workspace/test-website/css`
`rm -rf ~/workspace/test-website/css`
`rm -R ~/workspace/test-website/css`

`grep` fails to match those lines.

#### Some of the errors I get sometimes are:

When adding the -FxqE option:
`grep: conflicting matchers specified`

Any ideas?

Comment: What about using the absolute path instead?

Comment: The "grep: conflicting matchers specified" is because you cannot use -F and -E in the same grep command.

Comment: can you put your history file in a gist and share it (or at least enough of it to play with. I'm not getting an error when I run this (After removing -F -E conflicting arguments) but I'd like to test against real data

Comment: Better yet, run the script with `set -x` and gist the output.

Comment: @Albert it's because the people who is trying to solve this challenge may write the home `~` path in order to remove a folder or file. Absolute paths do work.

Comment: @gymbrall thanks for your suggestion. Actually the real data is each of those examples of the `rm` command I posted. These are simply appended to the `.bash_history` file and read from there. However, let me try switching between `-F` and `-E` to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be simplified: why do you need an array to hold the arguments?

```
function expect_commands {
    local label=$1
    shift
    for arg do
        arg=$( sed "s/ ~/ $HOME/g" <<< "$arg" )    # translate ~ to $HOME
        if grep -Fxq -e "$arg" -e "$arg/" -e "$arg " "$HISTFILE"
        then
            response "$label" $COUNT
        else
            tell_error "$label" $COUNT
        fi
    done
}
```

What is `$COUNT`? Avoid global variables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason why I need the array is because the user is asked to complete a task, in this case: _remove entire ~/workspace/test-website/css directory_, and he/she may input several `rm` combinations (absolute/relative paths) and command options.

The array holds a list of the possible answers.